# Having trouble keeping libcurl keep connection alive

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

so I just wanted to make a simple program that checks an IMAP server for new emails infinitely and I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "foo@yahoo.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "foobar");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.mail.yahoo.com/INBOX");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "SEARCH NEW");
    while (true) {
       res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

       if(res != CURLE_OK)
         fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
       curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return (int)res;
}
```

The weird thing is though that the results are not being updated automatically. I know this will work if I close the connection and re-open it but I would prefer to use the same exact curl handle if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about setting a [keepalive](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL.html) option because of a long operation?

Comment: I really don't know, will that solve the problem at hand?